# Possibly dystopian novel about telepathic 'lepping', set in the future

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy

I've been looking for this book for a while now but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Involved a bunch of teenagers that could talk to each other telepathically (pretty sure they called it 'lepping'). Think they met at some sort of bar in the sky, somewhere at the start of the book, and things got pretty weird from then on??

Some other details are that they travelled there in tubes above ground, rather than on roads. Pretty sure there was also a meat factory where steaks were grown on 'farms', similar to lab-grown meat.

If anyone knows of this one, it would be most appreciated, as it's driving me mad trying to find it!!! Only read it around 7 or so years ago in school and this is about all I remember. Thanks.

Comment: Likely one of the same answers as [Novel (dystopian?) where some of the population have telepathy, that they call "lepping"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217959/novel-dystopian-where-some-of-the-population-have-telepathy-that-they-call)

Comment: Neither *The Masters of Solitude* nor *The Galaxy Primes* start with teenagers meeting in a bar.

Comment: There is a sequel to [The Masters of Solitude](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1395266.The_Masters_of_Solitude) called [Wintermind](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1133019.Wintermind) but this doesn't match the *teenagers meeting in a bar* opening either.